# Uploading Text File to Input in Html/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type file in a form that I would like to be immediately read as a text file and used to update the value of a text input:

HTML:

```
<input type=file id='uploadfile' name='uploadfile' onchange="uploadCoordinates(this.form)">
```

JS:

```
function uploadCoordinates(form) {
       var file=form.uploadfile.value;
       var reader=new FileReader();
       reader.readAsText(file.value);
       form.coordinates.value=reader.result; 
}
```

Howveer, I get the following error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMFileReader.readAsText]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: https://portal.nersc.gov/project/als/ShirleyXAS/ShirleyXAS.js :: uploadCoordinates :: line 142" data: no]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to upload a text file to input in HTML/JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038919/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-text-file-to-input-in-html-js)

Answer (score 1):

try this there is error you are trying to read value.value

Correct code is

```
JS: function uploadCoordinates(form) {
       var file=form.uploadfile.value;
       var reader=new FileReader();
       reader.readAsText(file);
       form.coordinates.value=reader.result; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this by fixing the error is to further modify your code and @cons0ul's code.

```
var rPreviousText;
function uploadCoordinates(formVal) {
   var file = form.uploadfile;
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsText(file.value);
   form.coordinates.value = reader.result;
   rPreviousText = reader.result;
   showReadersText(reader.result);
}
function showReadersText(val) {
   alert(val); //I recommend using something better than alert.
}
```

This is far more reliable than either codes and has a method of showing the reader text that is in their txt file. If you don't need the `showReadersText()`, just delete it and replace it with whatever code you need. Please not that FileReader is not browser-friendly in more than half of the major browsers. It works well in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (at least when I tested them).