# Is it possible to upload a text file to input in HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some input boxes in a HTML form that need to be updated when the form loads and these values need to be uploaded from a text file.
A similar question was also asked here:
[Uploading Text File to Input in Html/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831707/uploading-text-file-to-input-in-html-js)

I have searched for this on the internet, but couldn't find any correct answer.
So I want to know whether it is possible or not?

Comment: yes, it's possible. use input type=file

Comment: Do you mean you have a text file you want to read and append into your html or you want to handle a form upload with js?

Comment: What values, what input boxes, what needs to be updated, what format is the file, where is the file, uploaded to where ... WTF maybe it would be more clear if you posted some code

Comment: for example there is a input box, it needs to be filled automatically at the start time when it is loaded, and i must be able to change it afterwards

Comment: Basically, you need to process an uploaded file and update the page/form accordingly based on the contents of the file, right?

Comment: Are you trying to do this purely on the client side, or do you have access to the backend as well?

Comment: i am trying to do this on the client side only

Comment: _“i am trying to do this on the client side only”_ – well then “uploading” is not really the right phrasing, is it? What do you _actually_ want to achieve?

Comment: I think OP is confused about exactly what is involved in processing said file. 

Basically there are two ways to do it: 

Either upload to a server, and then read the contents of the file from the server. This involves having some backend code to process the file and store it somewhere, if only temporarily. 

OR read the contents of the file from the user's computer with plain JS - in which case, my answer addresses that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you wish to go the client side route, you'll be interested in the HTML5 FileReader API. Unfortunately, there is not wide browser support for this, so you may want to consider who will be using the functionality. Works in latest Chrome and Firefox, I think.

Here's a practical example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files

And I also read here to find the `readAsText` method: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-readAsText

I would do something like this (jQuery for brevity): http://jsfiddle.net/AjaDT/2/

#### Javascript

```
var fileInput = $('#files');
var uploadButton = $('#upload');

uploadButton.on('click', function() {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('Your browser is not supported');
        return false;
    }
    var input = fileInput.get(0);

    // Create a reader object
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (input.files.length) {
        var textFile = input.files[0];
        // Read the file
        reader.readAsText(textFile);
        // When it's loaded, process it
        $(reader).on('load', processFile);
    } else {
        alert('Please upload a file before continuing')
    } 
});

function processFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.result,
        results;
    if (file && file.length) {
        results = file.split("\n");
        $('#name').val(results[0]);
        $('#age').val(results[1]);
    }
}
```

#### Text file

```
Jon
25
```

Comment: tried the above jsfiddle, in that i am able to browse the files, and select some text file, but when i submit upload button, nothing is happening, what is the reason for this? is it because of the browser issue? did the above code work fine for you ?

Comment: Yeah, works for me in Chrome and Firefox. Did the file you uploaded contain the text I suggested? Updated my answer to show that. However, parsing text is not really in the scope of this question. Once you have the text in a variable (in this case `file` inside of `processFile`), you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: yeah this works now.. i am sorry i also want to know how this works with php or when the file is on the server side ? i.e. when i have access with backend, in this case also i need to select a text file, match the text file values with the javascript ids and then enter the input values..

Comment: FileReader is also supported by IE 10. About support: http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader

Comment: @JonJaques in the above, if the text file contents are, Name: Jon     Age: 25, but i want to extract only 'Jon' in the first line and '25' in the second line and input them in the html boxes as it was done previously, is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Yes. As I said though, there are many different ways to parse a file, it really depends on what use case you have.. If you don't think it will be much more complicated than that, then you can forgo regexes, but at some point you will probably have to look into those. Updated my answer with a simple example above.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is great, but a bit outdated and it requires HTML & jQuery to run.

Here is how I do it, works in all modern browsers down to IE11.

```
/**
 * Creates a file upload dialog and returns text in promise
 * @returns {Promise<any>}
 */
function uploadText() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        // create file input
        const uploader = document.createElement('input')
        uploader.type = 'file'
        uploader.style.display = 'none'

        // listen for files
        uploader.addEventListener('change', () => {
            const files = uploader.files

            if (files.length) {
                const reader = new FileReader()
                reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    uploader.parentNode.removeChild(uploader)
                    resolve(reader.result)
                })
                reader.readAsText(files[0])
            }
        })

        // trigger input
        document.body.appendChild(uploader)
        uploader.click()
    })
}

// usage example
uploadText().then(text => {
     console.log(text)
})
// async usage example
const text = await uploadText()
```

Comment: Thanks–this is great! One side note: in some contexts, the call to `uploader.click()` won’t work, because some browsers require human intervention to initiate a file upload. (The current version of Chrome/Mac, for example, generates an error in the console log when it encounters that `uploader.click()` line.) In that case, you can leave out the `uploader.style.display = 'none'` line, and manually click the button to test it.