# adding .txt files through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a school project I am trying to complete. Its a fairly easy one, but due to my professors being in another country I am neither able to get answers from them frequently nor quickly.

I am trying to create a webpage that makes it so that when I click a link it causes it to load and append a .txt file underneath the sub navigation without changing any of the page.

This is my incomplete javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var massage = ('massage.txt')
    $('.selection').click(function() {
        $('.selection').append('massage');

    });
});
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
  <div id="content">
            <div id="spaselection">

                    <p class="selection">
                    Massage
                    Facials 
                    Laser Hair Treatment/Electrolysis 
                    Nails
                    </p>

            </div>
```

Comment: Where's the txt file located? Something you need to upload, or somewhere on the web?

Comment: Its something I need to upload

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038919/is-it-possible-to-upload-a-text-file-to-input-in-html-js

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what it is they're explaining?? I am not trying to upload a txt file to myself from a website I am trying to make it so when they click the word "Massage" it puts the text from the "massage.txt" file underneath it?

Comment: But where is **massage.txt** coming from? From what you mentioned earlier, you said the user's computer has this file. Well they would need to upload it into the browser for it to be handled.

Comment: I guess forward thinking is a good thing. It would be coming from the host server for my site. Right now it is being used in Dreamweaver so its file source is C://student/jason/beatrice/massage.txt...I hope that answers the question

Comment: If it can be referenced in a URL path that starts with http (or https), you can use AJAX to load that file in. If it's not, you need to find a way to allow that host server to be a web server and serve the appropriate file OR use [Server-Side Includes](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341).

Comment: Now here is a silly question...My school has a zip file with everything I would need to use ajax, but where would I download the plugin to use the .load function and when I am no longer at school? I will try the .load via URL thank you :)

Comment: Are you referring to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)? It's publicly available to anyone. It's a library which has the `.load()` function you seek. But I have a feeling you don't quite understand the nature of how all of this is tied together.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a file named 'massage.txt' in the same folder as your webpage, then there is a simple solution that involves only HTML. I'm sure you're aware of iFrame. You can use that to upload files from your folder, as well as websites not owned by you. Example:

```
<iframe src="massage.txt" type="text/plain"
content="file" class="upload" width="whateverPX"
height="whateverPX">If you see this message, 
massage.txt does not exist or your browser doesn't support iframes.</iframe>
```

Of course, you can style it whatever you want and change the size of it. Here is my finished version:

```
<iframe src="/student/jason/beatrice/massage.txt" type="
text/plain" content="file" class="upload" width="900px" height="800px" frameborder="0" 
script="autoUpload();">
Your browser does not support iFrames
</iframe>
<noscript>Your browser does not support Javascript.</noscript>
```

And yeah, I invented the iFrame type. That doesn't really matter. What matters is, it works. Tested in most major browsers and approved. According to W3Schools, iFrames are supported in at least 5/6 major browsers. Supported in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari, etc.